# Flask response - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to create a pytest for a flask REST server.

In one of the tests, i want to get the server's response.

This is the server's response:

```
return make_response(json.dumps({'myName': userName}), 200)
```

And this is what i am using in order to access it:

```
myFileId = response.json()['myName']
```

However, i get this error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I also tried this:
`response.myName` but this does not work obviously.

Comment: What does `request.status_code` return?

Comment: it returns 200.